# render add to cart using views

Tags: views, commerce

Is it possible to use views to render block with add to cart button, then add a contextual filter, so I can use it in panels?

For testing, I tried to make a simple view consisting of add to cart buttons and use it on a product page, but it displays nothing.

The same is with displaying pictures attached to product. I can see them when creating view in view UI but how do I pull out data from product so I can display them on product page using using views or just placing a block on a page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: ok I fugured it out. I had to enable permissions for viewing product - namely: View any Product product. Otherwise any content pulled from product would be forbidden to all users but administrator.

Comment: Please mark it as solved.

Comment: See issue: http://drupal.org/node/1276450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answered by user1031742

I had to enable permissions for viewing product - namely: View any Product product. Otherwise any content pulled from product would be forbidden to all users but administrator.